# /dev/urandom generate passsword for Windows 10 complexity requirments

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I have been trying to find the right syntax that will do the following:

1. Generate a password of a specified length (user able to input desired length)
2. Always adheres to the complexity requirements for Windows 10. (basically following item 2 here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/password-must-meet-complexity-requirements#reference
3. Uses `/dev/urandom`

I have managed to get so far with the below with the fold value acting as length option:

```
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9/*#' | fold -w 10 | head -n 1
```

However, this doesn't *guarantee* complexity - it's still relying on luck that at least three of the above categories will be included (number, uppercase, lowercase, special char etc).

How can I specify that this MUST choose from the three characters above. I'm sure it's just a small tweak needed, but not finding the right regex for this so far :(

Cheers
Shaun

Comment: Generate a few characters in each category separately. Then combine them randomly to create the full password.

Comment: Or add a test for whether it satisfies all req's, and retry until it does.

Comment: I thought about generating from each category separately but then I'd need to consider how many chars from each category I need to match the user inputted pwd length, not impossible I guess but adds some complexity. The test idea is an interesting idea - so an if statement with the regex and then a loop once met. I could explore this idea. I don't typically use bash or regex too much day to day so any pointers to the syntax welcome. Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: To find a suitable number of characters for each category is almost trivial: You know the minimum number needed per category, and the maximum number possible (so that you can do the other categories as well). Pick a random number in this range. Retry is possible, but then you have to verify after each retry that the password meets the requirement - and **this** is additional work, which you don't need if you generate only suitable passwords from scratch.

Comment: I want the user to be able to choose the length so the minimum and maximum are the same. i.e the user wants a 10 character password - I would then have to divide this up over the three required categories (lower,upper,special etc). This is doable but I was hoping I wouldn't need to delve into formulas for this. Also, if I end up with a password which has x number of lowercase, then following sequentially with x number of uppercase etc it would be more predictably as a password - unless there is a command that can jumble the characters around afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

From your linked [Complexity Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/password-must-meet-complexity-requirements#reference), emphasis mine:

> 2. The password contains characters from **three** of the following categories:
>
>    - Uppercase letters of European languages (A through Z, with diacritic marks, Greek and Cyrillic characters)
>    - Lowercase letters of European languages (a through z, sharp-s, with diacritic marks, Greek and Cyrillic characters)
>    - Base 10 digits (0 through 9)
>    - Non-alphanumeric characters (special characters): (~!@#$%^&*_-+=`|(){}[]:;"'<>,.?/) Currency symbols such as the Euro or British Pound aren't counted as special characters for this policy setting.
>    - Any Unicode character that's categorized as an alphabetic character but isn't uppercase or lowercase. This group includes Unicode characters from Asian languages.

Since you generate passwords according to `tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9/*#'` you can simplify a check for above complexity requirements. For instance, the last category cannot occur, so we don't have to check that.

Unfortunately, checking that 3 out of 4 categories are present is a bit complicated with `grep` , so I use `awk`:

```
</dev/urandom tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9/*#' | fold -w 10 |
awk '{c=0} /[a-z]/{c++} /[A-Z]/{c++} /0-9/{c++} /[*#]/{c++} c{print;exit}'
```

If you also want to implement the requirement of no user names ...

> 1. Passwords may not contain the user's samAccountName (Account Name) value or entire displayName (Full Name value). Both checks aren't case-sensitive.
>
>    The samAccountName is checked in its entirety only to determine whether it's part of the password. If the samAccountName is fewer than three characters long, this check is skipped. The displayName is parsed for delimiters: commas, periods, dashes or hyphens, underscores, spaces, pound signs, and tabs. If any of these delimiters are found, the displayName is split and all parsed sections (tokens) are confirmed not to be included in the password. Tokens that are shorter than three characters are ignored, and substrings of the tokens aren't checked. For example, the name "Erin M. Hagens" is split into three tokens: "Erin", "M", and "Hagens". Because the second token is only one character long, it's ignored. So, this user could not have a password that included either "erin" or "hagens" as a substring anywhere in the password.

... you can add the following check:

```
samAccountName=...
displayName=...
</dev/urandom tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9/*#' | fold -w 10 |
grep -vFf <(grep -Eo $'[-,._$ \t]{3,}' <<< "$samAccountName $displayName") |
awk '{c=0} /[a-z]/{c++} /[A-Z]/{c++} /0-9/{c++} /[*#]/{c++} c>=3{print;exit}'
```

Altough that has a few problems with unicode symbols (e.g. the display name `Schütz` is broken into `Schü` and `tz`. And then the `tz` is ignored because it is less than three characters long).

Comment: Hi Socowi - thanks for the advice. Apologies but I'm not overly familiar with awk. I can see the logic there where variable c is appended to each time it matches a category, and then I should be able to check the variable at the end of the run to ensure its >=3. I've tried to run this but it just outputs the generated password regardless of whether it matches. I've managed to see the generated text and the result of c by running this command: </dev/urandom tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9/*#' | fold -w 4 | awk '{c=0} /[a-z]/{c++} /[A-Z]/{c++} /0-9/{c++} /[*#]/{c++} c{print;print c;exit}'

Comment: What I basically want the routine to do is to always return a valid password (so I suppose a loop here is needed too, to return the first valid password generated and then stop)

Comment: Right, I have the if statement there to output a string if it matches 3 of 4 elements, but how can I evaluate variable c outside of the awk statement so I can loop the whole script automatically until it returns a compliant string? This is a learning curve for me!   code -  </dev/urandom tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9/*#' | fold -w 4 | awk '{c=0} /[a-z]/{c++} /[A-Z]/{c++} /[0-9]/{c++} /[*#]/{c++} {
if (c >= 3)
 {print;exit}
else 
 {print "no match";exit}
}'

Comment: I think I've got it! awk will continue here until it reaches c>=3, code is here: </dev/urandom tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9/*#' | fold -w 4 | awk '{c=0} /[a-z]/{c++} /[A-Z]/{c++} /[0-9]/{c++} /[*#]/{c++} {if (c >= 3){print;exit}}'. Is my logic right there?

Comment: @ShaunCroucher Oops, of course I meant `c>=3{print;exit}` instead of `c{...}` (which is basically `c!=0{...}`). I'm glad you found a solution yourself. `{if (c >= 3){print;exit}}` would work too.